# Crazy error when running a connector c++ program

Tags: cmake, clion, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-c

I have a problem with Connector/C++.
I'm using CLion as IDE and want to create a c++ program to interact with mysql database.
this is my CMakeList.txt file which i include c++/connector static and dynamic libraries in it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(cpp_programming)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0")

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Static Libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/libcrypto.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/libssl.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn8-static.lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn-static.lib)

# Dynamic Link Libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libssl-1_1-x64.dll)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mysqlcppconn-7-vs14.dll)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mysqlcppconn8-2-vs14.dll)
```

And i just include xdevapi.h header in my c++ source file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And i run file in Release mode in clion and i receive these errors:

**Error message i see in the clion console**

```
====================[ Build | cpp_programming | Release ]=======================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Kianoush\CLionProjects\cpp_programming\cmake-build-release --target cpp_programming -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target cpp_programming
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp_programming.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable cpp_programming.exe
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r05Value5printERSo[_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r05Value5printERSo]+0x21): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::print(std::ostream&) const'
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r05Value5printERSo[_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r05Value5printERSo]+0x2c): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r08internal14Warning_detail5printERSo[_ZNK6mysqlx4abi22r08internal14Warning_detail5printERSo]+0x87): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTCN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE0_NS1_6common5ValueE[_ZTCN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE0_NS1_6common5ValueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx4abi22r05DbDocE[.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx4abi22r05DbDocE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\cpp_programming.dir\build.make:97: recipe for target 'cpp_programming.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cpp_programming.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cpp_programming.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [cpp_programming.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_programming.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp_programming.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cpp_programming] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cpp_programming' failed
```

Do i make mistakes in linking dll files or static files ?

What solution do you suggest ?

please help me, this take me in trouble for many days.

[Full screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgnej.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Posting links to code or log messages is discouraged. Please post your **full** error message *as text* in your question post.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you need to link all those different libraries. For the mysqlcppconn libraries try linking only this one: `lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn.lib`.

Comment: Thank you, I do this but receive above error again.

Comment: What is the above error. The image is cut off and we cannot see the useful part of the error message. Please add the error message to your question post **as text**, not an image.

Comment: Hi, edited.....

Comment: I don't think you read the second part of my answer, you need to switch your compiler to VisualC++ to use these MySQL librares. Also, make sure your paths are correct, and that the `mysqlcppconn8.lib` library actual exists at the path `"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. You do not need to link all of these different libraries. You really only should require one `mysqlcppconn` library to be linked. To locate the library, try using [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html#command:find_library), and use it for linking instead. Your CMake file should reduce to something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(cpp_programming)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0")

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Find the mysqlcppconn library.
find_library(mysqlcppconn_LIB 
    mysqlcppconn8 
    HINTS ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR}/lib/vs14

# Static Libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${mysqlcppconn_LIB})
```

I'm not sure if you are using the `ssl` and `crypto` libraries, so add those back in if needed.

2. Your libraries (VisualC++) do not match the compiler (MinGW) you are using. To my knowledge, the MySQL Connector C++ [downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/8.0.html) do not provide a MinGW set of libraries; they only provide libraries that are built with the Visual Studio compiler. Thus, you need to switch to use the VisualC++ compiler to use these libraries. Another option would be to download the MySQL source and try to build it with MinGW, but that may be more difficult.

Hope this helps!